# Nested Json using Data Contract Class in AX 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, x++

I am trying to build nested JSON object to be sent as a body in the HTTPS Post Request. I was able to successfully do it in D365 FO using data contract class.
Below is the method for second level field in JSON nested data.

```
[DataMemberAttribute('supplier_info')]
public GA_EInvoiceIntegration_InvoiceSupplierContract supplier_info(GA_EInvoiceIntegration_InvoiceSupplierContract _supplier_info = supplier_info.parmValue())
{    
               if(!prmisDefault(_supplier_info))    
               {
                                supplier_info.parmValue(_supplier_info);    
               }    
               return _supplier_info;
}
```

But the same code is not working in AX 2012 R3.  May be due to the missing class(FormDataContract class).
How can I implement it in AX 2012?

Appreciate any tips.